# How do I set a vector's elements to point to the first element in an array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, pointers, variable-assignment, julia, ref

I've been learning Julia by trying to write a simple rigid body simulation, but I'm still somewhat confused about the assignment and mutating of variables.

I'm storing the points making up the shape of a body into an array of arrays where one vector holds the x,y,z coordinates of a point. For plotting the body with PyPlot the points are first transformed from local coordinates into world coordinates and then assigned to three arrays which hold the x, y, and z coordinates for the points respectively. I would like to have the three arrays only reference the array of arrays values instead of having copies of the values.

The relevant part of my code looks like this

```
type Rigidbody
    n::Integer
    k::Integer
    bodyXYZ::Array{Array{Float64,1},2}
    worldXYZ::Array{Array{Float64,1},2}
    worldX::Array{Float64,2}
    worldY::Array{Float64,2}
    worldZ::Array{Float64,2}
    Rotmat::Array{Float64,2}
    x::Array{Float64,1}
end
# body.worldXYZ[1,1] = [x; y; z]
# and body.worldX[1,1] should be body.worldXYZ[1,1][1]

function body_to_world(body::Rigidbody)
    for j in range(1, body.k)
        for i in range(1, body.n)
            body.worldXYZ[i,j] = body.x + body.Rotmat*body.bodyXYZ[i,j]
            body.worldX[i,j] = body.worldXYZ[i,j][1]
            body.worldY[i,j] = body.worldXYZ[i,j][2]
            body.worldZ[i,j] = body.worldXYZ[i,j][3]
        end
    end
    return nothing
end
```

After calling the body_to_world() and checking the elements with === they evaluate to true but if I then for example set

```
body.worldXYZ[1,1][1] = 99.999
```

the change is not reflected in body.worldX. The problem is probably something trivial but as can be seen from my code, I am a beginner and could use some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
body.worldX[i,j] = body.worldXYZ[i,j][1]
```

You're setting a number to a number here. Numbers are not mutable, so  `body.worldX[i,j]` won't refer back to `body.worldXYZ[i,j][1]`. What you're thinking of is that the value of an array will be a reference, but numbers don't have references, just the value themselves.

---

However, I would venture to say that if you're doing something like that, you're going about the problem wrong. You should probably be using types somewhere. Remember, types in Julia give good performance, so don't be afraid of them (and immutable types should be almost perfectly optimized after carneval's PR, so there's really no need to be afraid). Instead, I would make `world::Array{Point,2}` where

```
immutable Point{T}
  x::T
  y::T
  z::T
end
```

Then you can get `body.world[i,j].x` for the `x` coordinate, etc. And then for free you can use `map((i,j)->Ref(body.world[i,j].x),size(body.world)...)` to get an array of references to the `x`'s.

Or, you should be adding dispatches to your type. For example

```
import Base: size
size(RigidBody) = (n,k)
```

now `size(body)` outputs `(n,k)`, as though it's an array. You can complete the array interface with `getindex` and `setindex!`. This kind of adding dispatches to your type will help clean up the code immensely.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Using types for the points has been something I've considered but so far haven't gotten around to that. Can you elaborate on the choice of immutable though?

Comment: Okay, I tried making an array of Refs but it still won't update

Comment: Immutable means you can't change the values. So instead of changing the `x` of a Point, you'd have to make a new `Point`. However, this choice allows the compiler to essentially optimize "any overhead" (there's a tiny bit, but a v0.6 change is fixing that) of the type away, meaning that when using immutables everything becomes syntactic sugar to make code more readable without sacrificing performance. Mutable types can change (arrays are a mutable type), so they cannot be as well optimized.

Comment: Sorry, I was silly. Numbers are immutable, so you can't have a reference to a number. Remember, numbers never change, they are just replaced. So when the number gets replaced, how does a reference work?

Comment: Don't ignore types / multiple dispatch in Julia. You came for the fast loops, but in reality, all of that is just a quick way of describing to non-Julians what the type system gives you. The real force in Julia is the type system + multiple dispatch.

Comment: Sigh.. Pressed enter twice too early. So, I tried making an array of Refs but if I again set body.world.XYZ[i,j][1] = 9.99 the body.worldX array won't reflect the change.    About the immutable point, is there a difference in choosing it to be a vector or immutable? As it is, the world coordinates get updated and changed in every time step, which is why they are currently vectors.

Comment: Then you can have it as a mutable type. It'll be a little less optimized (but as optimized as a vector, probably a little bit more optimized than using a vector since it's less general). Then if `p` is a `Point`, you can change the values with `P.x=...`, or use `setindex!` to make an array interface to your `Point`. Once it's a type like that, you can do a whole lot really nicely using dispatch. But the loop you had there looked like you could definitely be doing something in a simpler way.